# Long sequence prediction with model trained on short sequence

Tags: keras, rnn, sequence

I'll start with a specific example.

I would like to train model which predict vector of [0-1]. Values close to 1 on specific range indicates that in those timesteps is particular activation word (audio).

I wonder if I train model on, for instance, maximum 10 second recordings, then if I give much longer audio spectrogram to predict wake-word occurences (minimum few minutes long), then would I get sensible results? Does LSTM/GRU network remember some maximum range of timesteps, depending of some parameters? Or should I slice my data for prediction to smaller parts, close to 10 seconds, as length of training data? What's approach to predict long sequences from model trained on small sequences?